# How to use res.render and res.redirect in the same function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am developing a widget for user login. Basically, when they input valid account details I want it to render the same page (using handlebars) and state something like "Account successfully validated" and then 3 seconds later redirect the user.

This is the current code I have

```
router.post('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;

    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.username = username;

                res.render('login.hbs', {
                    access: new hbs.SafeString('<p>Account successfully authenticated!</p>') // Display custom message
                });

                setTimeout(() => {
                    res.redirect('/admin'); // Redirect user
                }, 3000);

            } else {
                res.render('login.hbs', {
                    access: new hbs.SafeString('<p style="font-size: 1.2rem; margin-top: 2rem; color: red; font-weight:700;">Incorrect Username and/or Password!</p>')
                });
            }           
        });
    } else {
        res.render('login.hbs', {
            access: 'Please enter Username and Password'
        });
    }
});
```

However, whenever I try to do this I get the 'Cannot set headers after they have been sent to the client' Can someone please educate me on what the header system is and how I can fix this to get the desired result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res.redirect()` works by setting a `Location` HTTP header. Those headers must be sent before any content is delivered to the client via the response body.

As an alternative to handling this delayed redirect client-side, you could use the non-standardised* `Refresh` header that allows to specify a delay in seconds before the redirect happens. Just add

```
res.set({'Refresh': '5; url=/admin'});
```

before you call `res.render()`.

* *It was introduced by Netscape way back and since adopted by all major browsers, so despite never making it into the official HTTP standard, it's pretty safe to use it.*

And as a "bonus", if you were to solve it client-side, you would add

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=/admin"/>
```

to the header of your returned HTML markup, which does exactly the same.

Comment: Because I'm using res.redirect, for my res.get('/admin') how would i go about passing parameters such as my users username when i call the redirect function?

Comment: You don't need `res.redirect()` anymore when you use the header for the redirection. But the only way to pass any data to the page you're redirecting to would be via GET parameters in the URL: `/admin?username=jhadd24`